# Why am I getting a 403 forbidden on my entire local wampserver?

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I have wampserver installed locally and I run about 20 different projects on it. I recently made some changes to some config files but I forget what I did exactly. I believe I edited the php.ini.

Anyways I get a 403 forbidden on every webpage on the server. How can I determine what's causing the 403? The Apache error is the same every time and it looks something like this:

`[Sun Oct 04 21:36:07 2015] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.10.1/`

Comment: What version of WAMPServer & Apache are you running? Do you have Virtual Hosts setup, if so show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me..

```
<Location />
   Allow from all
   Order Deny,Allow
</Location>
```

I have included this code in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

**Edit :** This code is only for local server not safe for production server.

Comment: This change actually gives access to the whole disk that apache is installed on, so on windows for example the whole of the `C:` drive and on a *nix even more. If your network is not open to the internet, this is not too serious, but if it is, or you later want to see your site(s) on the internet, you are **giving away the keys to the kingdom**. As such it is a very dangerous and nooby mistake!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I totally agree with you. As mentioned in the question its  for local wamp server.

Comment: Unfortunately that how they start off, and then they want to show a friend or client and by that time they have forgotten they took some bad advise earlier on in their development process. They open up their router and **BAM** welcome one and all. _My PC is your PC_